# Submit apps to appaloosa store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Does anyone here know how It works when a user are going to download and Install a app that Is published on [appaloosa-store](https://www.appaloosa-store.com/)? Is It exact like app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have uploaded your app, you have to connect directly from your smartphone to the store you have created when you signed up. Then you will be able to download the app you've uploaded. 
And concerning your second question, in comparison with a public one, a private store is more secure. You will find many exclusive features like the ability to add a password in your store or to force the user to update his app,..
[Appaloosa](https://www.appaloosa-store.com/) is more for an enterprise use because that permits to keep your data private, your app is not shared with anyone.